# How to remove "CannotImport" error in Python-kivy?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, kivy, linux-mint

I am using linux mint, i have installed python-kivy using the instructions http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-11-10-or-newer but after running first program there is a error.
I am attaching both coding and error screenshot.
Please help me out.

```
from kivy.app import App

class TutorialApp(App):
    pass
if __name__=="__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call your file `new.py` - this conflicts with the `new` module in Python, which is causing a circular import.